# How to pass node v8 options to sl-pm?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, strong-parameters, loopback

We are using strongloop process manager for running my loopback app on production boxes, and using `sl-deploy` to deploy the code.

We are facing the below issue:-

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

on googling I found that the above issue can be somehow resolved by increasing `max_old_space_size` in the node options value.

I did the below change to run the app, and passed this variable before `sl-pm` process, but still facing the same issue, and found that my `slc` process are still using default value of max_old_space_size

```
/opt/node/bin/node **--max_old_space_size=3072**
/opt/node/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/bin/sl-pm.js --listen 8701 --base
/var/lib/strong-pm --base-port 3000 --driver direct
```

Comment: have you tried adding `--v8-options` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079918/configuration-max-old-space-size-in-nodejs ?

Comment: Already mentioned in the question, that it is done, but no success

Comment: Have uou tried to call sl in this way: node --max_old_space_size=3072 /usr/local/bin/sl-run .

Comment: Not yet, But trying it on one of the production machines, will update the findings in a day or two. Thanks